# Installing Two version of MSSQL SQL Server 2017 and SQL Server 2019 on same CENTOS 7 machine

Tags: sql-server, linux, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2019

Can we install Microsoft SQL Server version 2017 and 2019 on same OS for Linux especially CENTOS as we can do for Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CentOS is not a supported version of Linux to install SQL Server (for Linux) on, so it's recommended that you use one that is supported.

Regardless, however, of what operating system you install it on (supported or not), on Linux you can only run one instance at a time on a single host. The documation on [Work with multiple versions and instances of SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/work-with-multiple-versions-and-instances-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) explicitly states it is a Windows Only Feature.

If you do need to run multiple instances of SQL Server on the same physical host, then the recommendation is to use containers. Then you can run a single SQL Server (on Linux) instance inside each container.

This question is also answered in the SQL Server on Linux Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ) in the [Administration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-faq?view=sql-server-ver15#administration) section:

> **2. Does SQL Server on Linux support multiple instances on the same host?**
>
> We recommend running multiple containers on a host to have multiple distinct instances. This is easily achieved using docker, but each container needs to listen on a different port. For more information, see [Run multiple SQL Server containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-docker?view=sql-server-ver15#run-multiple-sql-server-containers).

Comment: You certainly can run more than one instance on a single host.

Comment: @AbBennett on Windows, yes... This question is **not** about windows.

Comment: Fair enough sorry